# button wont submit script

Tags: javascript, submit

I'm currently trying to make a script for educational purposes. Now I want to check the answers people give by using a little script. But I think everything is well-programmed, however it won't submit. Any ideas?

```
        <div>
            Ik<input id="invulvraag1" type="text" placeholder="h..."> Marie.
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Controleer</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var text = document.getElementById("invulvraag1").value;
                var text;
                // Het antwoord is correct
                if (text === "heet") {
                    text = "perfect, goedzo!";
                    // het antwoord is iets anders
                } else {
                    text = "helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.";
                }
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: where you want to submit form ?? its a part of server side

Comment: In else condition quotes are causing problem.
Use `"helaas.. het had 'heet' moeten zijn.";`  or `"helaas.. het had \"heet\" moeten zijn.";`

Comment: Anything in the error console?

Comment: @Pekka웃: Yes, there is. ;-)

Comment: @Mahi im sorry, the button is used for submitting the form, i made it in dutch ;)

Comment: @Shubham tried it, however it still doesnt do anything.. when i click the button on my web-app it just acts like a button, you see it changing color (as it is being pushed in real life) and then it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For frontend programming you will need to use console (dev tools).
 Press F12 or right click inspect element for safari.

In  console tab you will see : 
js error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'heet'
```

Fix : 
This line :

```
 text = "helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.";
```

must be :

```
text = "helaas.. het had 'heet' moeten zijn.";
```

OR

```
 text = 'helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.';
```

Comment: maybe another question for you. im going to want to use a diffrent script for every answer, is it possible to have this in an other document so it gets it scripts from there?

Comment: Please , create question with all details is best variant ...Its hard to understand question in one line from comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
        <input id="invulvraag1" type="text" placeholder="h...">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Controller</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        var text = document.getElementById("invulvraag1").value;
        var text;

        // Het antwoord is correct
        if (text === "heet") {
        text = "perfect, goedzo!";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

        // het antwoord is iets anders
        } else {
        text = "helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        }

        }
    </script>
    use above code it is useful
```

Comment: This Script will throw script error because of `text = "helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.";` . It will say heet is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post the form data on the server by using `<form>` `action` method then create button as

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return myFunction();">


 <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var text = document.getElementById("invulvraag1").value;
            var text;

            // Het antwoord is correct
            if (text === "heet") {
            text = "perfect, goedzo!";

            // het antwoord is iets anders
            } else {
            text = "helaas.. het had "heet" moeten zijn.";

            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            return true;
            }

  </script>
```

Or if you just want to call the client side function then run the code and click f12 in browser if there will be any error then it will throw in console